# Show only two select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically, i want it so every time someone clicks on the button it will show one select box and then they click it again it will show the other one. So my question is how can I make it so on click it will show a select box one at a time?

**Select box add function:**

```
function addChooseSub() {
    window["maxAppend"] = 3;
    maxAppend = maxAppend + 1;
    $("select.signUp[name=\"option" + maxAppend +"\"]").show();
    console.log("sdasd"+maxAppend)          
}
```

**Click Function:**

```
<script>
$('body').on('click', '.addSelect', function() {
    addChooseSub()
});
</script>
```

**Box HTML:**

```
<div class="signup box">
        Hello, <strong><?php echo $session->getSessionInfo("register", "firstName")." ".$session->getSessionInfo("register", "lastName"); ?></strong> and welcome to <strong>LetsChat</strong>, please choose up to <strong>5 courses</strong> you're currently taking.
        <hr>
        <form method="POST" action="#" class="chooseCourse">
            <select class="signUp" name="option1">
                    <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Course Option 1</option>
                    <?php $core->pullCourses(); ?>
            </select>
            <select class="signUp" name="option2">
                    <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Course Option 2</option>
                    <?php $core->pullCourses(); ?>
            </select>
            <select class="signUp" name="option3">
                    <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Course Option 3</option>
                    <?php $core->pullCourses(); ?>
            </select>
            <select class="signUp" name="option4" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Course Option 4</option>
                    <?php $core->pullCourses(); ?>  
            </select>
            <select class="signUp" name="option5" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="empty" disabled selected hidden>Course Option 5</option>
                    <?php $core->pullCourses(); ?>  
            </select>
            <div class="addSelect"> + </div>
            <input type="submit" name="signupSubmit" onclick="choosingSubjects()" class="purple btn signup" value="Finish" style="margin-top: 0;">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Edited the question, sorry for my 'vagueness'. 'So my question is how can I make it so on click it will show a select box one at a time?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is your `window.maxAppend = 3;` at the top of your function is resetting it every time your function is called.

There are a few ways to accomplish what you want, but the easiest will be to just move maxAppend outside of the function. This way, it will not get reset, and its value will be preserved from the last time it was called.

```
var maxAppend = 3;

function addChooseSub() {
    maxAppend++;

    if (maxAppend > 5) return;

    $("select.signUp[name=\"option" + maxAppend +"\"]").show();
    console.log("sdasd"+maxAppend)          
}
```

Comment: As does yours. ;) Both answers will just throw an error in the console, if that. With the skill of the rest of the page, it's not the end of the world. And I updated to fix it.

Comment: Now it is closer to mine, however I did not hardcode the number

Comment: Right, because I was following the original intent of what the OP showed. By having that on there, I assumed that the first three were already displayed, as if the student had to choose at least three, but could add two more.

Comment: Ah, I see that in the display none part.

Comment: Right. I'm approaching this as a Stack Overflow answer, and not a Code Review answer. There's a LOT more I would do to clean up the code, but with the apparent skills of the OP, I was keeping it at that level.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few more issues than I saw from the start.

- You need to move the counter outside the function
- There is no `hidden` attribute on an option.

Like this - assuming you want to initially have the last two SELECTS hidden and show next two SELECTs one by one

```js
var maxAppend = 3;
$(function() {
  $(".addSelect").on("click", function(e) {
    maxAppend++;
    if (maxAppend <= $("select.signUp").length) {
      $("select.signUp[name=\"option" + maxAppend + "\"]").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="signup box">

  <hr>
  <form method="POST" action="#" class="chooseCourse">
    <select class="signUp" name="option1">
      <option value="empty" disabled selected>Course Option 1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select class="signUp" name="option2">
      <option value="empty" disabled selected>Course Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select class="signUp" name="option3">
      <option value="empty" disabled selected>Course Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select class="signUp" name="option4" style="display: none;">
      <option value="empty" disabled selected>Course Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select class="signUp" name="option5" style="display: none;">
      <option value="empty" disabled selected>Course Option 5</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div class="addSelect">+</div>
    <input type="submit" name="signupSubmit" class="purple btn signup" value="Finish" style="margin-top: 0;" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The `addChooseSub` is tied to the `div.addSelect` above the submit button, so the form will not be submitted as each of these gets added.

Comment: I saw that now. Amended my answer